# Automatic Call Logging in Salesforce1 app

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a question regarding call logging in mobile app of Salesforce.

As we know that we can make a phone call via Salesforce 1 app. Now after the call is made, can we log a call automatically without the user intervention.

For eg:

If X calls Y. Now in the call log it should be like : X called y at so and so time, date and duration of the call.

is this possible.

Any insights would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this witha custom publisher action.   The "Log a Call" action has defaults, and your custom "call" action can as well, but will still required the "Save" button be pressed.

Alternatively, you can create a custom button such as "quick call log", which will invoke an apex method to generate the activity easily without the need for the user to press save or enter any detail.

Comment: Hey James,
Can that custom button be created for Salesforce 1 app and use it from there?
is there any useful code or link for this apex method so that I can learn and use it.

thanks

Comment: This should help: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=actions_overview.htm

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this on SF1. There is an app called LiiD for CRM that does this (http://liid.com/). The app logs the call automatically, tracks time and duration etc.

Comment: Are you affiliated with this app? (See: [Disclosure](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/promotion))

Comment: It looks like your post does answer the question, but you really should declare your affiliation with this product.